# Inflate view causes 40mb bump in RAM use

Tags: android, android-layout, memory, view, ram

I've been doing some debugging and finally came to a certain line that causes my app to quadruple RAM usege. This is the line in my fragment:

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments, container, false);
     return v;
 }
```

The **R.layout.comments** view is this:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:minHeight="60dp"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    android:weightSum="100" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_below="@+id/back">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"

        >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/colorsbg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:clipToPadding="false"

                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:minHeight="60dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totalupvotes"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="4022"
                    android:textColor="#fff"

                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/save"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:background="@drawable/starbackgroundbig"

                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="13dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/staricon"

                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/upvote"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:background="@drawable/upvotebackgroundbig"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="13dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/upvoteicon"

                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/downvote"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:background="@drawable/downvotebackgroundbig"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="13dp"

                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/downvoteicon"

                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/layoutright"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                android:paddingBottom="0dp"


                android:paddingStart="20dp"

                android:scrollbars="none">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Loading replies..."
                    android:textColor="#fff"

                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/subscribebg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"

                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:scrollbars="none">


                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/toggleama"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textOff="ENABLE AMA MODE"
                    android:textOn="DISABLE AMA MODE" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/commentsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        android:background="#ff141414"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/commentreply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|end"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"


        android:src="@drawable/reply"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="#E64A19"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="#ffb94018"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="#ffb23717" />

</RelativeLayout>


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressloading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"

    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

What would cause this view to use so much  memory? Am I inflating it wrong?

**EDIT:**
Here are the XML files for downvotebackgroundbig,ect.

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/clearbg" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/redbig" />
</transition>
```

and redbig

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#F34235" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my cases the image loading caused the problem. How large are those images you use in the layout ?

Comment: They are xxxhdpi standard material design icons, only about 400 bytes each (48x48)

Comment: What with the 'android:background="@drawable/starbackgroundbig"'

Comment: It's just a shape with a fill background

Comment: Okay, those shapes can be a problem. If you make a shape in android that is for instance a rectangle of 100 by 100, then  it will actually create an image of that size. How large is that shape exactly (bounding box) ?

Comment: It is a weight of 25 (25% width) and 60dp height each (there are three such image views). That is the final size of the drawable background area, the shape by itself doesn't have a set w and h

Comment: I just did a calculation 48M = an image of about 1700x1700 pixels. So I really suspect it is your background picture that is loaded. Do you maybe have an android:windowBackground set somewhere, or does the theme set on by default. <- note that a windowBackground is not the same as the background of your activity.

Comment: I have no backgrounds set. I have a large image view on a different fragment but I only get the huge spike in memory use for this inflation. I did code breaks everywhere and finally narrowed it down to that line. This fragment is in a vertical view pager that is within a horizontal view pager, and is the second view (first one is an image and a title). Unfortunately, I have no window backgrounds at all. This may be related, but I did a full mem dump and a large percent of the ram is being taken by a 9 million byte long array (byte[9000000] all with the value -1

Comment: Value -1 is basically opaque white. Really this sounds like the windowBackground to me. Probably the activity flickers briefly white when opened. I had that happen too. Can you try adding  <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item> to the style you use ?

Comment: Oh in the style? I set my window to black. Testing your code out though. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Setting it to @null saved me about 15mb of ram! Now I'm using 72 mb. Still high but definitely better! There has to be something else eating up my RAM. I'm using Facebook's fresco library for my large image (the first view in the pager is basically a full-activity sized image), and I removed that completely which resulted in barely any memory savings.

Comment: This is what I mean about a memory spike http://i.gyazo.com/8686429165e2e3bd2f6a3f7741b58712.gif

Comment: Hehe, maybe you can try setting it twice to null to save another 15Mb :)

Comment: Haha wish it was that easy. I use the same theme for all activities though. And that's strange that it is opaque white considering my entire app is almost exclusively black...

Edit: Wait the only view that isn't black is my sidebar, which is white. The memory spike also happens right when the sidebar loads....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78603/discussion-between-ccrama-and-werner-van-belle).

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating the view as you should, but your view contains an `ImageView`. Images take up a lot of memory, quite a lot more than on the disk/storage. This happends because the image is compressed when it is on disk (stored in a JPG, PNG, or similar format). Once you load the image into memory, it is no longer compressed and takes up as much memory as is necessary for all the pixels (typically width * height * 4 for RGBA_8888, or width * height * 2 for RGB_565). My bet is that this is the cause of the increased memory usage.

Comment: The images are transitiondrawables. They are xxxhdpi standard material design icons though, only about 400 bytes each (48x48). Could those really be the issue? I thought something that small would not really affect it much.

Comment: What about the backgrounds? **downvotebackgroundbig** - it even contains the word big :D

Comment: It's just a shape with a fill background :(